# Get animated matplotlib plot into plotly dash

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash

I have made an animation for the BubbleSort with Celluloid and want to bring the animation into Plotly Dash.

Here is the BubbleSort Code:

```
from vizualizer import Plot
from plotly.tools import mpl_to_plotly

def bubbleSort(data):

    # loop throught all data elements
    for l in range(len(data)):
        # Compare all elements
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if i < (len(data)) - 1:
                if data[i] > data[i + 1]:
                    # swap numbers
                    data[i], data[i + 1] = data[i + 1], data[i]

                    Plot(i + 1, data)
```

And here the code for the animation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera


fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)


def Plot(highlight,data):
    x = list(range(len(data)))

    colors = list(len(data) * 'k')
    colors[highlight] = 'r'

    plt.bar(x, data, color=colors)
    #plt.scatter(x, data, color=colors)

    camera.snap()
```

And finally the full dash code

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from vizualizer import camera
import random
from bubbleSort import bubbleSort
from plotly.tools import mpl_to_plotly

size = 30
data = random.sample(range(size), size)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Hands on Python Sorting Algorithm',
            style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Tabs(className='four.columns', id='tabs', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Bubble Sort', value='tab-1'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Merge Sort', value='tab-2'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Quick Sort', value='tab-3'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Heap Sort', value='tab-4'),


    ],
        style={'align-items':'center'}
             ),
    html.Div(id='tabs-content')
])

@app.callback(Output('tabs-content', 'children'),
              [Input('tabs', 'value')])
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Bubble Sort'),
            html.P('Here goes the description for the Bubble Sort'),
            dcc.Graph(id='test', figure=bubbleSort(data))
        ])
    elif tab == 'tab-2':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Merge Sort'),
            html.P('Here goes the description for the Merge Sort')
        ])
    elif tab == 'tab-3':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Quick Sort'),
            html.P('Here goes the description for the Quick Sort')
        ])
    elif tab == 'tab-4':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Heap Sort'),
            html.P('Here goes the description for the Heap Sort')
        ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

I thought I can make a `Graph component` and call the `bubbleSort(data)` function to plot.
But I get the `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop` error.
Is it possible to plot an animated plot into dash?
If yes, whats the best way to do this?